# I want to get the public post from user only from facebook graph api

Tags: facebook

I want to get the public post from user only. For example when I run below query -
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=buy+AND+nokia+AND+lumia&limit=100&type=post

I get post from category = community. I want to get the post from users only not communities. Is there way to filter the results